# HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add give that error Response is not available in this context

Tags: c#, cookies, httpresponse, httpcookie

I want to try create cookie in csharp class

```
HttpCookie musteriCookie = new HttpCookie("Musteri");
musteriCookie.Name = "END";
musteriCookie.Value = "END";
musteriCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);


HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(musteriCookie);
```

but in last line

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(musteriCookie);
```

it give that erro  Response is not available in this context.
How can I create cookie or localstorage in c# static class and then read that cookie in javascript file

Comment: Please clarify: in which context do you want to add the cookie? ASP.NET MVC? Web API? Web Forms? The question as is can't be answered.

Comment: Well, what *is* the context?

Comment: When I say context I mean: in which *environment* are you trying to create the cookie? What kind of web application is? Which framework are you using?

Comment: When ASP.NET is processing a request, the `HttpContext` provides access to details about that request - the request, the response, session, cookies, etc. But you could be at a point when there is no response to modify, or even no context at all. Depending on which type of application you're in it helps to read about the lifetime of a request and understand the different points at which you might access it.

Comment: it is asp.net mvc project.I am using this code in service layer .In this class   public class GameService :IGameService  ..............